# Convert Array Type into Object or Object type into Callback

Tags: typescript, generics, type-conversion

I am currently working on one Project where I have one `Object` type something like below

```
type MyObject = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
  three: boolean;
}
```

and this is used in many places in my project but with different approach something like below

```
type MyCallback = (one: string, two: number, three: boolean) => void
```

so I want type in some way that I can write one thing and automatically second thing is converted.

**What I tried**

I try to convert `Callback` into `Object` because its looks easy

```
type CallbackArray = Parameters<MyObject> // results: [one: string, two: number, three: boolean]
```

Now I tried to convert this array into an Object something like below but I didn't get the desired output, don't know why ;_;

```
type ConvertArrayIntoObject<T extends any[]> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[key]
}
```

So Can someone please help me to findout what the problem is or give me an approach of the conversion of `Array type into Object` or `Object type to Callback`?

Comment: Both conversions are basically impossible*. You can't convert the object type to the tuple, because the order of properties in an object type is not observable by the type system. You can't convert the tuple with named indexes to the object because the names can't be observed by the type system.

Comment: So is there any way that I define above thing in such a format that it converts into both the formats from that thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider a refactor, it would involve making changes in the codebase from this:

```
type MyObject = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
  three: boolean;
}

type MyCallback = (one: string, two: number, three: boolean) => void
```

To this:

```
type MyObject = {
  one: string;
  two: number;
  three: boolean;
}
type MyCallback = (props: MyObject) => void
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your "base" type in the following format:

```
type Base = [
  ["one", string], 
  ["two", number], 
  ["three", boolean]
]
```

This guarantees that bother *order* and *names* are known.

The format can now be converted to both *object* and *function* types.

```
type ToObject<B extends any[]> = {
  [I in B[number] as I[0]]: I[1]
}

type ToCallback<B extends any[]> = 
  (...args: [...{ [I in keyof B]: B[I][1] }]) => any
```

The resulting types would like like this:

```
type MyObject = ToObject<Base>
// type MyObject = {
//     one: string;
//     two: number;
//     three: boolean;
// }

type MyCallback = ToCallback<Base>
// type MyCallback = (args_0: string, args_1: number, args_2: boolean) => any
```

*Structurally*, these types are identical to the types you want to have. There is no programmatical way to create *named tuples*. That is why the names of the parameters in the callback are just `args_0`, `args_1`, ...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAICECGBnOBeWBtYssCIB7AO2jwBpZlQAnASyIHMBdCnfUAdwPNiIFcAtgCNo1FrDaY8oABbVopCkIIEANtEREmwbWChwAKgQDyQgFbQAxqAA88WNAAeoaEQAmyWJvCYmAPlgMAG9JAElYegRMfmFRJi9PUMwABiYmAC5YJIBGbQBfEAgYWCMAYURVVSFESwBrOwdnVw8vIh9-QNgACgA6PsRqBmRMzD6eoKxwyNrocAIAMwQMqNCmTFzYPKYASkCA7xA9YoBZcFMLa06jc6tbJFQ-YAB6J9giuFOby%20Dn19xcYjQTJUOiMADcv3%20uE4BEyMRE1AhLyhbzkCkyyjUGiISNeBSOH3A5Uq1TqVwIxKqNXq92gj2R71gp0ppNqnS6AyGAH1ksCaPQGBROcgudk4YIEULBiKAEwYlTqTS7ND7NpAA)